# Unknown setter '_date_time' Carbon / Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, hhvm

I have my installation of laravel 4 under HHVM, and i set up as a accessory on my eloquent an converter date from SQL date to human.

doing something like that:

```
public function getDateSpanAttribute($value)
{
      return $value = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$this->created_at)->diffForHumans();
}
```

This method **work well under php5**, no error just work. On HHVM this accessory throw me an exception saying,

> {"error":{"type":"InvalidArgumentException","message":"Unknown setter
>   '_date_time'","file":"/var/www/mynextmatch/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php","line":542}}

I saw the source of Carbon on that row and it is the magic method `__get()` to give this problem but i cannot figure out why it happening.

I will appreciate same help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error on `HHVM` but one thing is for sure that an `accessor` method doesn't contain any argument, it should be ([Manual](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)):

```
public function getDateSpanAttribute()
{
      return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->created_at)->diffForHumans();
}
```

You just need to return the `property` not setting anything, if you want to set anything then it would be a `setter/mutator` method which acepts a value as argument.

Comment: True, but it doesn't matter in fact.

Comment: Confused! Won't it matter if he doesn't provide the parameter while the method accepts one ? Method will complain about it, right ? But it doesn't matter if he provide it and doesn't use it in his code, like he is doing it now @deczo.

Comment: yes true, it doesn't matter with the problem but thank you, you are right! :)

Comment: You are welcome and please post the solution as an answer when you get it fixed, I'll delete my answer @Fabrizio.

Comment: Hopefully I'll do, I'm still having this issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue but think mine is tied to creating a session creation after logging in (
InvalidArgumentException Unknown setter '_date_time'). Mine is installed on HHVM 3.1 running on Ubuntu 14.04. I have the same set up using Ubuntu 12.04 and am not having this issue.

```
10. InvalidArgumentException
…/­vendor/­nesbot/­carbon/­src/­Carbon/­Carbon.php542
9. Carbon\Carbon __set
<#unknown>0
8. DateTime __sleep
<#unknown>0
7. serialize
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Session/­Store.php222
6. Illuminate\Session\Store save
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Session/­Middleware.php126
```